How do I refresh Players to change their skin?
I am trying to change the skins of the players on the Server. I've looked it up and found that you would need to send the correct packets with one being the deletion and the other the adding of the player, but at my version (1.21.1 nms installed with Spigot buildtools --> using Mojang Mappings).
I tried it with other packets like the ClientboundRespawnPacket, but that didn't work either. This is my current code:
@Override
    public boolean onCommand(@NotNull CommandSender sender, @NotNull Command command, @NotNull String s, @NotNull String[] strings) {
        String PlayerName = sender.getName();
        if (!(sender.hasPermission("northmclobbyutils.duckify")) && sender instanceof Player) {
            sender.sendMessage("§cYou do not have permission to use this command!");
            return true;
        }
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            PlayerName = "Console";
        }
        for (Player p : sender.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
            System.out.println(p.getName());
            CraftPlayer cp = (CraftPlayer) p;
            ServerPlayer sp = cp.getHandle();
            sp.setCustomName(Component.literal("§6Duck"));
            PropertyMap pm = sp.getGameProfile().getProperties();
            pm.removeAll("textures");
            System.out.println("Duckifying " + p.getName());
            pm.put("textures", new Property("textures", "ewogICJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiIDogMTczMTIxMzc0NTk1NywKICAicHJvZmlsZUlkIiA6ICI1OWJlOTUyY2EyNjc0OWE4OTM1YmQ5MGQxNmMyN2M4OCIsCiAgInByb2ZpbGVOYW1lIiA6ICJUaGVQZW5zcGlubmV1ciIsCiAgInNpZ25hdHVyZVJlcXVpcmVkIiA6IHRydWUsCiAgInRleHR1cmVzIiA6IHsKICAgICJTS0lOIiA6IHsKICAgICAgInVybCIgOiAiaHR0cDovL3RleHR1cmVzLm1pbmVjcmFmdC5uZXQvdGV4dHVyZS80MTlkNTQ3NTk3YTQ2NmM0MWY1YmI3YjE0Y2MyMTZmMTk2ZDNhZjI0YjJhYWQ3MWZjMjlkNWE4ZTlkY2RiZmY5IgogICAgfQogIH0KfQ==", "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"));
            updatePlayerSkin(p);
            sp.connection.send(new ClientboundPlayerInfoRemovePacket(new ArrayList<>(List.of(sp.getUUID()))));
            sp.connection.send(new ClientboundPlayerInfoUpdatePacket(Action.ADD_PLAYER, sp));
        }
        sender.sendMessage("§aAll players have been duckified!");
        return true;
    }

what happens now is, that the Players disappear from the tablist but their skins stay the same.

You can hide and show again the player. To do that, you have Player#showPlayer and Player#hidePlayer that should be used like that:
for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    setDuckPlayerSkin(p);
    for (Player all : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        all.hidePlayer(plugin, p); // hide player
        all.showPlayer(plugin, p); // show it again
    }
}

This will do in a safer way the 2 last line that send packets.
